# Decoding function gives error that will not be fixed by encoding it

Tags: python, windows, encoding, decoding

My code encrypts a file, and the second part will decrypt it. It works fine with txt files but if I put a .docx through it it throws up an error that I can not figure out how to solve. Below is the main part of the code that I need help with.

I already did encoding and decoding it using examples from this site, but it does not work, it just gives the same error.

```
dwdfa = input('Enter the entire file directory plus extension you wish to decrypt:')
dodf = open(dwdfa,"r+").read()
a = len(dodf)
dfirst = dodf[a-2]+dodf[a-1]+dodf[:a-2]
for i in dfirst:
    dsecond = (chr(ord(i) - 5))
    Word.append(dsecond)
    dsecond = ''.join(Word)
print(dsecond)
new = open(dwdfa + "1", "w")
new.write(dsecond)
```

I expected the output to give me the decoded version of the text and print it out, however it just gives the same encrypted text and the error of:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position
>   18: character maps to

If possible try the answer simplified as I do not understand conversion of bytes to string or anything else like that.
The r+ is there to open the file, if needed, ill add the encryption bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I put a .docx through it"? Are you trying to read a word file like you would read a text file?

Comment: Much as I hate to admit it, yes as I do not know how else to open a file, read the contents and use them.

Comment: Yeah, `open()` is the good way to read a file, however 'docx' is a binary format. Try to open a docx with notepad++ and you'll see what I mean... If you want to get the content of a word document, you'll have to use some specialized library, like: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docx is a binary format (to be precise, a zip archive containing XML files), and therefore needs to be processed as `bytes` rather than `string` in Python.

If you want to simply encrypt arbitrary files (eg. images, executables) you will need to rewrite the function to work on bytes instead of characters (for example, that -5 caesar shift `(chr(ord(i) - 5))` would be `(i - 5 + 256) % 256`, and add `b` to the flags of the `open()` calls. Text files will then still remain text files unless they contain Unicode (which will be broken). Encrypted docx files will be gibberish, so they can't be opened in Word until decrypted.

But if you want to work on the *text* of your docx files, you will need a special docx library (eg https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Note that doing the processing in-place (leaving formatting and layout intact) may not be trivial.